# Dash Encoding converting a java function to PHP

Tags: java, php, regex, encoding

I'm trying to convert a java function to equivalent PHP function.

**Java:**

```
/**
 * Dash Encoding:
 *
 * Zeta-Jones <=> Zeta--Jones
 * Blade - The Last Installment <=> Blade---The-Last-Installment
 * Wrongo -Weird => Wrongo---Weird (decodes to => Wrongo - Weird)
 * Wrongo- Weird => Wrongo---Weird (decodes to => Wrongo - Weird)
 */
private static Pattern dashes = Pattern.compile("--+"); // "--" => "-"
private static Pattern blanks = Pattern.compile("\\s\\s+"); // "   " => " "

private static Pattern hyphen = Pattern.compile("(?<=[^-\\s])-(?=[^-\\s])"); // like "Zeta-Jones"
private static Pattern dash = Pattern.compile("[\\s]-[\\s]|-[\\s]|[\\s]-"); // like "Blade - The Last Installment"
private static Pattern blank = Pattern.compile("\\s+");


public static String dashEncode(String s) {
if (s == null) return s;
s = blank.matcher(
    hyphen.matcher(
        dash.matcher(
            dashes.matcher(
                blanks.matcher(s.trim()).replaceAll(" ") // compress embedded whitespace "   " => " "
            ).replaceAll("-") // trim and compress multiple dashes "---" => "-"
        ).replaceAll("---") // replace dash with surrounding white space => "---"
    ).replaceAll("--") // replace single "-" => "--"
    ).replaceAll("-"); // replace blanks with "-"
return s;
}
```

So far I have:

**PHP**

```
function dashEncode($str) {
     // replace blanks with "-"
     $str = str_replace(' ', '-', $str);

     // replace single "-" => "--"
     $str = str_replace('-', '--', $str);

    return $str;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know java very well, but as `Pattern.matcher()` is used with `replaceAll()` *always* in the java function, this could be written as `preg_replace()` in PHP. And basically that's it.

When you copy the regular expression patterns, add delimiters as `preg_replace` needs those. Next to that the expressions look compatible.

```
/**
 * Dash Encoding:
 *
 * Zeta-Jones <=> Zeta--Jones
 * Blade - The Last Installment <=> Blade---The-Last-Installment
 * Wrongo -Weird => Wrongo---Weird (decodes to => Wrongo - Weird)
 * Wrongo- Weird => Wrongo---Weird (decodes to => Wrongo - Weird)
 */
function dashEncode($s) {
    static $pattern = array(
        'dashes' => "--+",     // "--" => "-"
        'blanks' => "\\s\\s+", // "   " => " "

        'hyphen' => "(?<=[^-\\s])-(?=[^-\\s])",  // like "Zeta-Jones"
        'dash'   => "[\\s]-[\\s]|-[\\s]|[\\s]-", // like "Blade - The Last Installment"
        'blank'  => "\\s+"
    );

    $matcher = function($name, $s, $with) use ($pattern) {
        isset($pattern[$name]) || die("pattern '$name' undefined."); 
        return preg_replace("~{$pattern[$name]}~", $with, $s);
    };

    $s = 
    $matcher('blank',
        $matcher('hyphen',
            $matcher('dash',
                $matcher('dashes',
                    $matcher('blanks', trim($s), " ") // compress embedded whitespace "   " => " "
                , "-") // trim and compress multiple dashes "---" => "-"
            , "---") // replace dash with surrounding white space => "---"
        , "--") // replace single "-" => "--"
    , "-"); // replace blanks with "-"$matcher('blanks', trim($s), " ");  // compress embedded whitespace "   " => " "
    return $s;
}
```

Comment: It's not really a port, you either should create a class out of it or unroll the nested function calls, because this does not make much sense inside a global function. I just did it that way for playing and to demonstrate that it's actually `preg_replace` and `trim` in PHP.